# How would you deal with equivalence relation and equivalence classes with functions??

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, relations, equivalence-relations

Suppose a function $f:A→B$ is given. Define a relation ~ on $A$ as follows:

$a_1$~$a_2$ ⟺ $f(a_1)$ = $f(a_2)$

Since ~ is an equivalence relation, it induces a partition of $A$ into equivalence classes. Describe these equivalence classes in each of the following cases. ($R$ is the set of real numbers).

(a) $A = B = R, f(x)=x^2$

(b) $A = B = R, f(x)=|x|$

(c) $A = R×R , B = R, f(x,y)=x+y$

my approach:

(a): the equivalence class contains no elements because the square of different numbers is different.

(b) : the equivalence class contains the set of real numbers.

(c): don't know about c

Is my approach anywhere near to correct? I am not so sure about the answers. please help!

Comment: note that $(-x)^2=x^2$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting formula in your question as you have been told on your first question. In general, you may want to read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to improve the quality of your questions and avoid down votes and close votes.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I have formatted the formulas and made the necessary edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting your approaches with "*the* equivalence class contains …" as if there was only one equivalence class in each example. This is wrong. For each $x\in A$ there is an equivalence class $[x]=\{y\in A\mid x\sim y\}$ and this is never empty as it always contains $x$ itself.

In the first example consider $x=2$. We have $x\sim y$ if and only if $x^2=y^2$ so $y^2=4$, which has the solutions $-2$ and $2$. This means that $[2]=\{-2,2\}=[-2]$. The same argument shows that $[x]=\{-x,x\}$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ with $x\neq 0$. Finally, since $y^2=0^2$ has the unique solution $y=0$, we have $[0]=\{0\}$ as the only equivalence class with just one element, while all other classes have two elements.

With this input I'll leave it to you to try the other examples again.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach in the first question is wrong, because the square of $x$ and $-x$ are the same,

though $x$ and $-x$ are different numbers unless $x=0$.

Likewise, $\lvert x \rvert=\lvert -x \rvert$, so again the equivalence classes are $\{x,-x\}$ where $x\in\mathbb R$.

For the last one, $(x_1,y_1)\sim(x_2,y_2)\iff x_1+y_1=x_2+y_2.$  Say $x_1+y_1=c$.

Then the points equivalent to $(x_1,y_1)$ lie on the line $y=-x+c$.